# How to transfom a distance vector to the adjacent cells to centred matrix of distance

Tags: r, coordinates, raster, r-raster, adjacency-matrix

I want to recover the distance matrix to a focal point `my_point` that represents the center of the matrix. At this point I could do :

```
        library(raster)
        set.seed(123)
        m168 <- matrix(1, nrow=13, ncol=13)
        m168[7,7] <- 0
        r <- raster(ncol=1000, nrow=1000)
        values(r) <- round(runif(ncell(r)) * 5)
        REP_UTM <-  '+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'
        r <- projectRaster(r, crs = REP_UTM)
        my_point <- c(500000, 560000)
        cells_a <- cellFromXY(r,my_point)
        xy_point <- xyFromCell(r, cells_a)
        a<- adjacent(r, cells=cells_a, directions=m168, pairs=FALSE)
        xy_a <- xyFromCell(r, a) 
        dist_to_a <- pointDistance(xy_a, my_point, lonlat=FALSE)
```

But I can't transform the vector `dist_to_a` into 13*13 square matrix. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Cool. `length(dist_to_a)` is 168, but 13*13 is 169, normally you would probably want to do sth like `matrix(dist_to_a, 13, 13)`.

Comment: @jay.sf yes, I want to add 0 (distance to itself) in the center of the matrix and keeping the order of the distances in the matrix as the adjacent cells. Because I want to use this to calculate the weight matrix after.

Comment: What do you think about `d2 <- length(dist_to_a)/2;matrix(c(dist_to_a[1:d2], 0, dist_to_a[(d2+1):length(dist_to_a)]), 13, 13)` then?

Comment: You may put that as your own answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

@jay.sf thank you very much, meanwhile I foud a solution :

```
dist_to_a <- append(dist_to_a, 0, 84) 
dist_to_a <- matrix(dist_to_a, nrow=13, ncol=13)
```